# Not all touch-events are fired in array.map react

Tags: reactjs, touch, touch-event

I want to add events listeners onTouchStart, Move and End to img tag in array.map function, as a result its catch only one event listener(onTouchStart), but if I set this listeners to div with class="header-added-heroes" all 3 listeners work, I read about binding 'this' to array.map and its catch only onTouchStart, I would be grateful for any information on this question.

```
{this.props.addedHeroes.map( function(el) {
            return (<a name={el.link} key={uniqueId()} className="heroes__link">
              <div className="hero"> {console.log(' map this : ', this === that)}
                {
                  <img className="hero__image"
                    onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
                    onTouchMove={this.handleMove}
                    onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
                    src={el.image}
                  />
                }
              </div>
            </a>);
          }, this )}
```

full code:

```
import React from "react";
import uniqueId from "lodash/uniqueId";
import HeroCounter from "../../images/HeroCounter.svg";

class HeaderAddedHeroes extends React.Component {
  state = {
    heroes: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    showCloseButton: 0
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onTouchStart = this.onTouchStart.bind(this);
    this.onTouchEnd = this.onTouchEnd.bind(this);
    this.handleMove = this.handleMove.bind(this);
  }

  handleMove() {
    console.log('moved');
    this.setState({ showCloseButton: 1 })
  }
  onTouchStart() {
    console.log('started');
    this.setState({ showCloseButton: 2 })
  }
  onTouchEnd() {
    console.log('ended');
    this.setState({ showCloseButton: 3 })
  }

  render() { var that = this;
    return (
      <header className="header-added-heroes"> { console.log(' this : ', that)}
        <div className="header-added-heroes" 
             onTouchMove={this.handleMove} 
             onTouchStart={ this.onTouchStart } 
             onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}>
                  { this.state.showCloseButton }
        </div>
        <div className="heroes">
          {this.props.addedHeroes.map( function(el) {
            return (<a name={el.link} key={uniqueId()} className="heroes__link">
              <div className="hero"> {console.log(' map this : ', this === that)}
                {
                  <img className="hero__image"
                    onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
                    onTouchMove={this.handleMove}
                    onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
                    src={el.image}
                  />
                }
              </div>
            </a>);
          }, this )} 
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: so the problem is that `onTouchMove` and `onTouchEnd` is not fired? And why do you need that `console.log` inside render? Please remove it, and make arrow function for map `this.props.addedHeroes.map((el) =>{`

Comment: yes, onTouchMove and onTouchEnd is not fired, forgot to say that initially started with the arrow function, and it also caught only onTouchStart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use arrow function.

Solution was: to remove ‘uniqueId()’

```
{this.props.addedHeroes.map((el, i) => {
            return (<a name={el.link} key={i} className="heroes__link">
              <div className="hero">
                  <img className="hero__image"
                    onTouchStart={this.onTouchStart}
                    onTouchMove={this.handleMove}
                    onTouchEnd={this.onTouchEnd}
                    src={el.image}
                  />
              </div>
            </a>);
          }
)}
```

Comment: I removed key={uniqueId()} and now it works, hmm , may be because after TouchStart its rerender and change key, thanks to all

Comment: Great! Maybe because new id is generated every time. I updated the solution for others to see.

Comment: good, but be careful to use indexes as keys, if the order of the elements may change, it will affect performance, [link](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) to clarify this moment